# C pointer to pointer warning

Tags: c, pointers, warnings

I get a warning when i point to a pointer. I am not sure why; the types are the same.

```
char delay_buffer1[40];
char delay_buffer2[40];
char** delay_buffer_front;
delay_buffer_front = &delay_buffer1;
```

the objective is to swap buffers:

```
void swap_string_buffer(void** pointer, void* buffer1, void* buffer2) {
  printf("pointer: %u. buffer1: %u. buffer2 %u\n", pointer, buffer1, buffer2);
  if(*pointer == buffer1) *pointer = buffer2;
  else *pointer = buffer1;
}
```

example code:

```
copy_content_to(delay_buffer_front);
swap_string_buffer((void**) delay_buffer_front, (void*) delay_buffer1,(void*)delay_buffer2);
fprintf(file, "%s", delay_buffer_front);
```

> warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>      delay_buffer_front = &delay_buffer1;

Comment: "the types are the same." Not completely true. A pointer to a pointer is not of same type as a pointer to an array.

Comment: delay_buffer1 == &delay_buffer1 = &delay_buffer1[0]

Comment: How would you call `swap_string_buffer`? Please show code a small [MCVE].

Comment: ... and what's the purpose of `delay_buffer_front`? Please explain what exactly `swap_string_buffer`  is supposed to do. Show a [MCVE] with expected output.

Comment: ... but what is it supposed to do??? Please show a complete example of what the contents of all buffers should be _before_ and _after_  the call to `swap_string_buffer`

Comment: swap the stringbuffer: the pointer (delay_buffer_front) should act same the way as a pointer to a backbuffer/frontbuffer

Comment: @Sollertis please don't explain, just  show a complete example of what the contents of all buffers should be _before_ and _after_ the call to `swap_string_buffer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the types are the same.

No, they aren't. You're probably confused (this is quite common) by the fact, that the identifier of an array *evaluates to a pointer to its first element* in nearly all contexts (exceptions are e.g. with the operators `&` and `sizeof`).

But that doesn't change the fact that **an array is an array and a pointer is a pointer**.

This is a *pointer to a pointer*:

```
char **delay_buffer_front;
```

What you probably wanted was a *pointer to an array*:

```
char (*delay_buffer_front)[40];
```

Or you might simply have wanted a plain pointer pointing to the first element of the array:

```
char *delay_buffer_front;
```

With that declaration, you can just assign the array's identifier because as explained above, it evaluates to such a pointer:

```
char *delay_buffer_front = delay_buffer1;
```

Comment: Upvote for the difference between pointers and arrays.  That `char (*buf)[40]` syntax hurts to look at, though.  That looks exactly like an error I made in my first serious C design, being new to C and converting an application from Pascal to C around 1984 or so.  "Pointer to array" is a natural data type to use in Pascal, but usually a notational burden in C.

Answer (score 1):

It means exactly that, the two pointers are incompatible. It's more an error than a warning.

You probably want this:

```
char* delay_buffer_front;
delay_buffer_front = delay_buffer1;
```

instead of:

```
char** delay_buffer_front;
delay_buffer_front = &delay_buffer1;
```

Answer (score 0):

As all you want is to swap the buffers you dont have to create a pointer to a pointer. Simply create an intermediate pointer of similar type and use it for swapping.

```
char* delay_buffer_front; //Intermediate pointer to store the address of first buffer
delay_buffer_front = delay_buffer1; //Store the address of the first buffer in the 
                                    //intermediate pointer.
```